# Como fazer select no banco envolvendo foreign key e primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho um problema, tenho duas tabelas que estao relacionadas apartir da chave estrangeira e a chave primaria desse jeito:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cargo(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
nome_cargo varchar(50) not null,          "supervisor,gerente, etc..."
salario_cargo DECIMAL NOT NULL,
tipo_cargo VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,        "administrador ou funcionario comum"
PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS funcionario(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
rg VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
senha VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
id_cargo INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
    ALTER TABLE funcionario ADD foreign key (id_cargo) REFERENCES cargo (id);
```

Todo cargo tem um id e o id_cargo da tabela de funcionario serve para identificar qual o cargo desse funcionario, porem, nao sei como fazer o select para apartir do Email do funcionario eu conseguir saber se ele é administrador ou funcionario comum, tentei alguns codigos mas nenhum deu certo, alguem me ajuda please

Answer (score 6):

Roda essa consulta:

```
SELECT NOME, EMAIL, NOME_CARGO, TIPO_CARGO
FROM FUNCIONARIO 
INNER JOIN CARGO ON CARGO.ID = FUNCIONARIO.ID_CARGO
WHERE EMAIL = 'seuemail@hotmail.com'
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado msm, do jeito que eu precisava... vlw